# EmguCV, failed to allocate memory

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, memory, emgucv

I tried to adapt the example MotionDetection from Emgu examples folder. The only important thing I changed is that I don't capture images directly from webcam but create Image<,> from Bitmap. Basically instead of

```
using (Image<Bgr, Byte> image = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame())
```

i use

```
using (Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(bmp))
```

where `bmp` is `Bitmap` that I captured from webcam using other methods.

[Here's the full code.](https://github.com/artemisvision/emgu_openCV/tree/master/Emgu.CV.Example/MotionDetection)

The part I used and adapted:

```
public Bitmap ProcessFrame(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        using (Image<Bgr, byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bmp))
        using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage())
        {
            if (_forgroundDetector == null)
            {
                _forgroundDetector = new BGStatModel<Bgr>(image, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BG_STAT_TYPE.FGD_STAT_MODEL);
            }

            _forgroundDetector.Update(image);

            _motionHistory.Update(_forgroundDetector.ForegroundMask);

            #region get a copy of the motion mask and enhance its color
            double[] minValues, maxValues;
            Point[] minLoc, maxLoc;
            _motionHistory.Mask.MinMax(out minValues, out maxValues, out minLoc, out maxLoc);
            Image<Gray, Byte> motionMask = _motionHistory.Mask.Mul(255.0 / maxValues[0]);
            #endregion

            image[0] = motionMask;

            double minArea = 100;

            storage.Clear();
            Seq<MCvConnectedComp> motionComponents = _motionHistory.GetMotionComponents(storage);

            foreach (MCvConnectedComp comp in motionComponents)
            {
                if (comp.area < minArea) continue;

                double angle, motionPixelCount;
                _motionHistory.MotionInfo(comp.rect, out angle, out motionPixelCount);

                if (motionPixelCount < comp.area * 0.05) continue;

                DrawMotion(image, comp.rect, angle, new Bgr(Color.Red));
            }

            double overallAngle, overallMotionPixelCount;
            _motionHistory.MotionInfo(motionMask.ROI, out overallAngle, out overallMotionPixelCount);
            DrawMotion(image, motionMask.ROI, overallAngle, new Bgr(Color.Green));

            return image.ToBitmap();
        }
    }

private static void DrawMotion(Image<Bgr, Byte> image, Rectangle motionRegion, double angle, Bgr color)
  {
     float circleRadius = (motionRegion.Width + motionRegion.Height) >> 2;
     Point center = new Point(motionRegion.X + motionRegion.Width >> 1, motionRegion.Y + motionRegion.Height >> 1);

     CircleF circle = new CircleF(
        center,
        circleRadius);

     int xDirection = (int)(Math.Cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180.0)) * circleRadius);
     int yDirection = (int)(Math.Sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180.0)) * circleRadius);
     Point pointOnCircle = new Point(
         center.X + xDirection,
         center.Y - yDirection);
     LineSegment2D line = new LineSegment2D(center, pointOnCircle);

     image.Draw(circle, color, 1);
     image.Draw(line, color, 2);
  }
```

However, the program throws an exception:

`An unhandled exception of type 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll. Additional information: OpenCV: Failed to allocate 121651200 bytes`

here:

```
_forgroundDetector = new BGStatModel<Bgr>(image, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BG_STAT_TYPE.FGD_STAT_MODEL);
```

Windows 7, 64x, program is build as 'Any CPU', 'Prefer 32-bit'. I use the newest Emgu 2.4.9-beta.

It happens when I use 1920x1080 bitmaps (3MB). When I use two different cameras in app window (704x576 and 352x288, I modified program so I can have images from multiple cameras), it happens too (not with the single low-resolution one though). The program runs without problems when I don't detect motion with this method.